# Looking for Python example of AWS User Pools custom authentication flow

Tags: amazon-cognito

In Amazon's [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/) an example handler of a trigger is given in JavaScript.

The JavaScript example ends with `context.done…` but the Python `context` variable doesn't have a `done` function.

How can one write trigger handlers for AWS User Pools?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, the answer turns out to be straightforward.

```
def handler(event, context):

    event['response']['autoConfirmUser'] = False
    event['response']['autoVerifyEmail'] = False
    event['response']['autoVerifyPhone'] = False

    return event
```